# HibernateException: Unable to access lob stream

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-criteria

I have a problem. I have a Spring Boot project using Hibernate and I can not query an OID in the database.

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "documento_oid")
private byte[] documentoOid;
```

Query:

```
if (tupled) {
        return em.createQuery(getTupleQuery())
                .setMaxResults(1)
                .getResultList().stream().findFirst().map(t -> (T) getWrappedInstance(t)).orElse(null);
    } else {
        return em.createQuery(getQueryT())
                .getSingleResult();
    }
```

[image]

Error: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access lob stream

Help me!

Comment: Did you see this? https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12393 There it's related to autocommit somehow.

Comment: Yes, I see, but it did not work

Answer (score 4):

Adding following application properties make it work for us:

```
spring.datasource.autoCommit=false
```

Comment: In my case workeds adde in application.properties 
''spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false''

Comment: Could you please describe shortly why this property solve the issue? Thanks!